SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED with Azure AI Search/ Cognitive Search (Langchain)
I want to write my embeddings to an Azure AI Search vectorstore. However, I keep getting SSL errors.
import os
    
from langchain_community.vectorstores.azuresearch import AzureSearch
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAIEmbeddings, OpenAIEmbeddings

os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"] ="xxxxxx"
os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"] ="https://xxxx.openai.azure.com/"
os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION"] ="2023-05-15"

vector_store_address: str = "https://xxxxx.search.windows.net"
vector_store_password: str = "xxxxxxxxxx"


embeddings: AzureOpenAIEmbeddings = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
            model="examplemodel"
            )

index_name: str = "demo"
vector_store: AzureSearch = AzureSearch(
    azure_search_endpoint=vector_store_address,
    azure_search_key=vector_store_password,
    index_name=index_name,
    embedding_function=embeddings.embed_query,
    
)

This is the error I keep getting:
File ~/Projects/dnv_nace_classifier/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/transport/_requests_basic.py:401, in RequestsTransport.send(self, request, proxies, **kwargs)
    398     error = ServiceRequestError(err, error=err)
    400 if error:
--> 401     raise error
    402 if _is_rest(request):
    403     from azure.core.rest._requests_basic import RestRequestsTransportResponse

ServiceRequestError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)

What can I do to make this work? I already installed CA certificates.
